# How to obtain generalized barycentric coordinates for n-sided polygon?

Tags: linear-transformations, interpolation

Quadrilateral linear basis functions(generalized barycentric coordinates) are defined as:

[image]

What are the steps to calculate the above functions?

Is it possible to obtain basis functions for a 5 sided polygon(pentagon) or in general n-sided polygon?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _basis functions_?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key terms are *generalized barycentric coordinates* and *mean value coordinates*.

Here are two representative papers on the subject. There are plenty more.

- Michael S. Floater, [Generalized barycentric coordinates and applications](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/acta-numerica/article/generalized-barycentric-coordinates-and-applications/62321A5281E90552020B728B0F5D4D0C), *Acta Numerica*, Volume 24, 2015, pp. 161-214 [[pdf](http://www.mn.uio.no/math/english/people/aca/michaelf/papers/gbc.pdf)]
- Kai Hormann,  Michael S. Floater, [Mean value coordinates for arbitrary planar polygons](https://doi.org/10.1145/1183287.1183295), *ACM Transactions on Graphics*, Volume 25, 2006, pp. 1424-1441 [[pdf](https://www.mn.uio.no/math/english/people/aca/michaelf/papers/barycentric.pdf)]